# Comparative analysis of TensorFlow-Quantum, Pennylane, and Qiskit, to implement quantum CNNs

Tags: qiskit, machine-learning, pennylane

I am currently working on a project wherein I have to implement a Quantum Convolutional Neural Network. The best options for NISQ devices are hybrid algorithms, so I will try integrating quantum layers into existing CNN architectures. The primary idea is to utilize either Quantum Filters as they do in Quanvolutional NNs or to utilize PQCs as Convolutional Layers.

Please provide a comparative analysis of these packages based on your experience. The primary factors to consider include integrability with Classical Models, availability of QML tools such as optimizers and different encoding schemes, and availability of simulators and circuit visualizers. Which package would serve best for this project?

I am currently quite familiar with TensorFlow and Qiskit but do not mind learning other languages. Additionally, I have written code for QML models however I have done that from scratch and not used existing packages.

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which part of the CNN (the convolution or the backpropagation) do you intend to substitute quantum algorithms for?

Comment: As currently phrased, I'm afraid this question will be closed as it's quite opinion-based. I suggest asking instead for the different functionalities handled by each framework

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience in pennylane, which is designed primarily for QML. You can easily define a `qnode` and integrate it into backend ML frameworis like pytorch or tensorflow. See [examples](https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/qml/blob/master/demonstrations/tutorial_qnn_module_tf.py)